# Format of POJO for nested JSON?

Tags: java, gson, retrofit

So lets say the JSON response is:

```
[{ "data" : { "item1": value1, "item2:" value2 }}]
```

How do you get the values 'value1' and 'value2' when you must first access data?

If the fields were at the root then I could just have the method return a POJO with those field names.

---

I basically want the below to work.

```
@GET("/path/to/data/")
Pojo getData();

class Pojo
{
public String item1;
public String item2;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try below code to convert your json string to Pojo object with required fields using Gson library.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

JsonArray jsonArray = gson.fromJson (jsonString, JsonElement.class).getAsJsonArray(); // Convert the Json string to JsonArray

JsonObject jsonObj = jsonArray.get(0).getAsJsonObject(); //Get the first element of array and convert it to Json object

Pojo pojo = gson.fromJson(jsonObj.get("data").toString(), Pojo.class); //Get the data property from json object and convert it to Pojo object
```

or you can define your nested Pojo class to parse it.

```
class Pojo
{
    private String item1;
    private String item2;

    //Setters and Getters
}

class Data
{
    private Pojo data;

    //Setters and Getters
}

ArrayList<Data> yourArray = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<List<Data>>(){}.getType());
```

EDIT : Try below code to get value1 and value2 using Retrofit.

```
class Pojo
{
    private String item1;
    private String item2;

    //Setters and Getters
}

class Data
{
    private Pojo data;

    //Setters and Getters
}

class MyData
{
    private ArrayList<Data> dataList;

    //Setters and Getters
}

IService service = restAdapter.create(IService.class);
MyData data = service.getData(); 

ArrayList<Data> list = data.getDataList(); // Retrive arraylist from MyData

Data obj = list.get(0); // Get first element from arraylist

Pojo pojo = obj.getData(); // Get pojo from Data 

Log.e("pojo", pojo.item1 + ", " + pojo.item2);
```

Comment: How do I get the json string when using Retrofit?

Comment: @RodL. As per Retrofit [documentation](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), Retrofit uses [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) by default to convert HTTP bodies to and from JSON. If you want to specify behavior that is different from Gson's defaults (e.g. naming policies, date formats, custom types), provide a new Gson instance with your desired behavior when building a RestAdapter.

Comment: @RodL. I am not familiar with Retrofit